# Illustrator: changing the opacity of fill and stroke independently won't work

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, stroke, fill

I've read various threads on how one can change the opacity values of stroke and fill individually by going to the `Appearance` panel. Unfortunately I cannot do that and I'mm stuck.

As you can see in the picture, when I'm selecting the yellow triangle and going in the `Appearance` panel, I get a `fill` and `stroke` option, but when I adjust them, nothing happens to my shape. This is a mixed object but even when I expand fill & stroke and ungroup the shape, I cannot adjust the fill opacity.

I want to adjust all three triangles' fill opacity without affecting the stroke. Please help.

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 13):

You should expand the small triangle on the appearance panel and adjust as usual -

[image]

If it does not work - probably the problem it the way you created the shapes

Comment: That is a gigantic appearance panel

Comment: @JohnB That is retina induced screenshot conversion effect

Comment: Jeez! Had no idea this was here. Even adjusted the opacity on the very next line (which controlled the whole object).